# Errors on the coding of HTML

Tags: java

```
<% page language="java" contentType="text/html charset-UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

I have this statement before starting my HTML part. I followed this from a book but when I tried it, it's showing error. How can this be resolved?

Comment: um... and the error is...?

Comment: We need some context here. Is it in your `JSP` page?

Comment: @Hovercraft I've got syntax error.It says insert ';'.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Yes it's my jsp page

Comment: The problem is I did not add the @ symbol. It was suppose to be <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html charset-UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed a semi-colon AND = here:

```
contentType="text/html charset-UTF-8"
```

Should be:

```
contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: Still getting an error

Comment: You also missed an `=`. Updated my answer.

Comment: I was still getting an error. But when I do this it's fine----<% page language="java"; contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"; pageEncoding="UTF-8"; %>  Is it acceptable?

Comment: Hmm, it might have been a formatting issue then (ex. a hidden newline character). Yes, putting the semi-colons in as you have done is acceptable. Everything between `<%` and `%>` is just regular Java code, so putting the `;` in is technically more accurate.

Comment: Anytime my friend, happy coding! :D